# postgresql function to update each row based on IF ELSEIF conditional

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, psql

I am trying to create a postgresql function that will be executed by a cron job every 30 minutes. This function will execute an if else conditional and update a column based on the current time and other column values.

I keep getting a syntax issue at the beginning of the IF statement and cant understand why:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "scheduled_active_start"
LINE 7:      IF scheduled_active_start <= executionTime AND schedule...
                ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "scheduled_active_start"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 144
```

Here is the postgresql function I am trying to create:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION updatePostActivity()   RETURNS void AS $$

DECLARE
    executionTime timestamp = Now();
BEGIN
    UPDATE  post
        IF scheduled_active_start <= executionTime AND scheduled_active_end > executionTime AND is_active != true THEN
             SET is_active = true;
        ELSEIF  scheduled_active_end <= executionTime AND is_active != false THEN 
            SET is_active = false;
        END IF;
END;
$$   
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax of the [`UPDATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html) statement clearly stays that there is nothing between `UPDATE` and `SET` keywords except the table definition. The `IF` statement is absent in the SQL at all (as I know). Use [`CASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) statement instead:

```
UPDATE post SET
  is_active = CASE 
    WHEN scheduled_active_start <= executionTime AND scheduled_active_end > executionTime AND is_active != true THEN true
    WHEN scheduled_active_end <= executionTime AND is_active != false THEN false
  END
WHERE -- Filter to avoid updating whole table
  (scheduled_active_start <= executionTime AND scheduled_active_end > executionTime AND is_active != true) OR
  (scheduled_active_end <= executionTime AND is_active != false);
```

PS: `is_active != true` equal to `not is_active` and `is_active != false` equal to just `is_active`